# Why does ויאמר almost never use לאמר, and why does וידבר almost always use לאמר?

Tags: words, tanach

It seems that [whenever Tanach says ויאמר](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%95%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh%2FTorah|Tanakh%2FProphets|Tanakh%2FWritings&tvar=0&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance), "and he said," it almost never uses the word לאמר, "saying."<sup>1</sup>

Conversely, [whenever Tanach says וידבר](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%95%D7%99%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh%2FTorah|Tanakh%2FProphets|Tanakh%2FWritings&tvar=0&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance), "and he spoke," it almost always uses the word לאמר, "saying."<sup>2,3</sup>

לאמר is also used by other verbs, but this pattern is striking among these two verbs specifically.

1. Does anyone comment on this phenomenon, that וידבר is almost always used in conjunction with לאמר, and that ויאמר and לאמר are almost always used exclusively?
2. Are there any reasons brought as to why this is the case?
3. (Bonus points!) Is there a general rule brought for why the cases below are exceptions?

---

<sup>1</sup>The exceptions seem to be Bereishis 9:8, 21:22, 34:4, 42:37, 43:3, 47:5; Shemos 7:8, 12:1, 31:12, 35:4; Bamidbar 7:4, 15:37, 20:23, 26:1, 27:6, 31:25, 32:25; Devarim 2:2, 9:13; Yehoshua 1:1, 2:2, 3:6, 4:1,15,21, 7:2, 17:17, 22:8; Shoftim 8:9, 20:28; Shmuel 1:7:3, 1:17:26,27, 1:24:10, 2:5:6, 2:17:6; Melachim 1:1:11, 1:13:31, 2:9:12; Yirmiya 26:12,18,  28:11, 32:6; Yonah 3:7; Chagai 1:13; Zechariah 1:14, 2:4, 3:4, 4:6,13; Divrei Hayamim 2:32:12. Yes, I know that seems like a lot, but when there are several thousand instances of ויאמר, a couple dozen of them being combined with לאמר is nothing.

<sup>2</sup>The exceptions seem to be Bereishis 41:17; Shemos 32:7, 33:1; Vayikra 10:12,19; Bamidbar 18:8, 21:5; Melachim 1:13:7,12, 1:21:6, 2:1:7,9-13,15,16; Yechezkel 40:4,45, 41:22.

<sup>3</sup>This does not include the times when וידבר does not immediately introduce a quote. Often the passuk uses וידבר...ויאמר, "and he spoke...and he said," as in Vayikra 16:1-2 et. al. Often it says that someone spoke *something* without providing the quotation, as in Shemos 6:9, וידבר משה כן, "and Moshe spoke thusly," et. al.

Comment: My understanding has been that *vayedaber* is typically translated as "spoke" for the very reason that it is a verb that is focused on the action of speaking rather than the content of what was said, in contrast to *vayomer* which is already focused on the content so should not typically require a *lemor* which would be redundant.

Comment: @Loewian Consider דבר אלינו קשות, the archetype from which we see that דבר is "harsh" speech. I'm not sure whether that necessarily disproves what you're saying, but something to think about.

Comment: I think that is in line with the distinction since its commenting on the action as opposed to the content.

Comment: ויאמר ה׳ אל משה לדבר

Comment: You already know about the "harsh speech"  aspect. I think the 1st Rash"i in parshat *Va'era* explains why "Vayedaber" is used whenever G-d relates mitzvoth to Moshe. If you find it, inform me, please. Very thorough analysis you did, here, BTW. I have to delve into this, later. Good Q!

Comment: @DanF I’m not sure whether that Rashi can be generalized; he says that Hashem spoke harshly in response to Moshe asking למה הרעתה. The second Rashi addresses the usage of שם הויה by mitzvos, but not the verb used.